# how to adjust accuracy only for 1's?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Suppose I have such data :

```
x1      x2     x3       y
0.85   0.95   0.22      1
0.35   0.26   0.42      0
0.89   0.82   0.82      1
0.36   0.14   0.32      0
0.44   0.53   0.82      1
0.75   0.78   0.52      1
```

I predict binary classification but the only thing that matters ,is the correct prediction of the 1s, and if the prediction is 0, it will not affect my accuracy.

I simply used the following code :

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But this code also includes zeros in its accuracy.

How can I apply to the network that only the prediction of 1 is important ?

In other words, During fitting model, if the prediction was zero , this zero predication does not apply to the model accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you care about `precision` of the model. Precision means for all instances that you predict 1, what portion of them is correct.

If yes, use `tf.keras.metrics.Precision()` as metrics.

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])
```